# How to "async" a part of the DOM or delay a Laravel request?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a page which can load a lot of datas through a `foreach` with Laravel.

The way I see it I'm looking for a way to delay it until the rest of the page is fully load so eventually you could look at the others informations while those datas are loading.

You have an example on [this page](http://dev.agencedevoyage.com/autotour-californian-dream-en-rdv-sur-place-et-htls-standard_31546).

(In screen the part Im looking to delay)
[image]

So I'd like to do something maybe like BlockUI but without blocking the whole page.
Any tip or indication to what could help me would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: You can load the page without the data, put a loader GIF in the place where the data will go, and then make an AJAX request to the server and replace the placeholder as soon as you get the response.

Comment: You mean like Angular?